# FormCollection Check if Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, formcollection

In this conditional statement I have tried the last portion in order to try and execute a section of code if my Form Collection is empty.

```
if ((myDT == null) || (myCollection.GetKey(0).ToString() == "heatSearch") || (myCollection == null))
{
    //some code here
}
```

Each time I run the code and the Form Collection is empty, at which time this condition should be true, my application crashes and I receive this error:  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Some more information...this check is being performed in an ActionResult called by an AJAX post.  The post is what fails and returns the error at this line shown here:              `<b> Source File: </b> c:\Users\D\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TheMProject(1)\TheMProject\Models\HomeModel.cs<b> &nbsp;&nbsp; Line: </b> 936`

Line 936 is the one with the if.

Comment: What line in your code gives the error? It is not the `if` one, is it?

Comment: `AllKeys.ToString()` does not make much sense. Test it: `System.String[]`

Comment: @Conrad Clark Yes, it happens on the line containing if.

Comment: @John Willemse  Yes, thats a typo

Comment: I think you are calling a collection element out of the `if` block

Comment: @Conrado Costa Not sure I follow you but I have just pasted above the exact line of code from my application

Comment: Sorry, but that is a completely different line of code now... now it makes sense to get that error.

Comment: @John Willemse  It previously worked before I added the last check to run the same code in the event the Form Collection was null or empty

Comment: Now I see what is wrong, I show below in a answer, you're calling the myCollection.GetKey(0) before to test if myCollection is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix it:

```
if ((myDT == null) || (myCollection == null) || (myCollection.GetKey(0).ToString() == "heatSearch"))
{
    //some code here
}
```

You're calling `myCollection.GetKey(0)` before test if `myCollection` is null.

Comment: Ok.  Replacing (myCollection == null) with (myCollection.Count == 0) works correctly.  Thank you for pointing out that the GetKey check cant come first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection f)
{
    if (f.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

        return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((myDT == null) || (myCollection == null) || (myCollection.Count > 0) )
{
    //some code here
}
```

is what I'd do